# eyeD3 fails to run on RHEL 8.8

Tags: rhel, eyed3

For the past couple of months, I have been unable to get eyeD3 to run on my RHEL8.8 system without displaying error messages.

Any execution of eyeD3 results in Python errors:

```
[michael@ares audio_file_maintenance_scripts]$ eyeD3
eyed3.plugins:ERROR: Bad plugin ('mimetype.py', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/eyed3/plugins')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/eyed3/plugins/__init__.py", line 56, in load
    mod = __import__(mod_name, globals=globals(), locals=locals())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/eyed3/plugins/mimetype.py", line 33, in <module>
    _python_magic = MagicTypes()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/eyed3/plugins/mimetype.py", line 18, in __init__
    magic.Magic.__init__(self, mime=True, mime_encoding=False, keep_going=True)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'mime'
No audio files found.
[michael@ares audio_file_maintenance_scripts]$
```

pip3 shows that I have eyeD3 version 0.9.2:

```
[root@ares ~]# pip3 list
DEPRECATION: The default format will switch to columns in the future. You can use --format=(legacy|columns) (or define a format=(legacy|columns) in your pip.conf under the [list] section) to disable this warning.
asn1crypto (0.24.0)
beautifulsoup4 (4.6.3)
borgbackup (1.1.18)
cffi (1.15.1)
chardet (3.0.4)
configobj (5.0.6)
configshell-fb (1.1.28)
convert2rhel (1.3.1)
cryptography (3.2.1)
cssselect (0.9.2)
dataclasses (0.7)
dbus-python (1.2.4)
decorator (4.2.1)
deprecation (2.0.7)
dnspython (1.15.0)
ethtool (0.14)
eyeD3 (0.9.2)
file-magic (0.3.0)
filetype (1.0.5)
gpg (1.13.1)
html5lib (0.999999999)
idna (3.3)
iniparse (0.4)
iotop (0.6)
isc (2.0)
kmod (0.1)
libcomps (0.1.18)
llfuse (1.3.6)
lxml (4.2.3)
nftables (0.1)
packaging (20.1)
perf (0.1)
pexpect (4.3.1)
pip (9.0.3)
ply (3.11)
psutil (5.4.3)
ptyprocess (0.5.2)
pycairo (1.16.3)
pycparser (2.21)
pygobject (3.28.3)
pyinotify (0.9.6)
pyparsing (3.0.9)
PySocks (1.6.8)
python-augeas (0.5.0)
python-dateutil (2.6.1)
python-dmidecode (3.12.2)
python-linux-procfs (0.7.0)
pyudev (0.21.0)
PyYAML (3.12)
requests (2.20.0)
rpm (4.14.3)
rtslib-fb (2.1.75)
schedutils (0.6)
selinux (2.9)
sepolicy (1.1)
setools (4.3.0)
setuptools (39.2.0)
six (1.11.0)
slip (0.6.4)
slip.dbus (0.6.4)
sos (4.5.3)
SSSDConfig (2.8.2)
subscription-manager (1.28.36)
syspurpose (1.28.36)
systemd-python (234)
targetcli-fb (2.1.53)
urllib3 (1.24.2)
urwid (1.3.1)
webencodings (0.5.1)
wheel (0.31.1)
[root@ares ~]#
```

Prior to what I assume was a change in the system due to a routine RedHat update a couple months ago, I routinely called eyeD3 from a script that copied tags from a FLAC file to an MP3 file, and there were no errors reported.

Now every instance of eyeD3 displays the error message listed above.

I don't have a lot of familiarity with Python.

Google searches on the error messages also show a similar issue with several versions of RedHat Fedora, so I'm assuming it's something in the RedHat default Python layout that accounts for this, but I haven't yet found an answer for how to resolve it.